# How to handle possible muiltiple/nonexistent search parameters with MySQL/PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Say I have these tables in MySQL

```
table actors
id  int  11  primary key auto_increment
name  varchar  30
sex   varchar  10

table movies
id  int  11  primary key auto_increment
name  varchar  30
type  varchar  30

table actors_movies
actor_id  int  11
movie_id  int  11
```

And assume I have a form in HTML that allows users to search for actors by parameters they define.

For example, a user might search just for actors with the name "John", or they may search for actors who are male and have acted in a "Drama"-type movie, or they may search for actors in the movie with the name "Batman" who are female, or they may search for actors who are in a "Drama" movie AND/OR (they choose which) a "Thriller" movie.

My solution is a very clunky PHP script that builds a prepared statement piece by piece to query the database with this depending on what parameters it is given.

My solution works, but is this the only possible way? I find my solution to be really clunky and as I add more possible parameters it just gets worse.

**because I was asked for an example of what I'm doing**

here's some pseudocode for what my script basically does

```
query = "Select * from actors 
         left join actors_movies on actors.id = actors_movies.actor_id
         left join movies on movies.id = actors_movies.movie_id"

Then for each possible parameter it does something like this

if(actors.sex given)
   query append("where actors.sex ="
   for each sex given
      query append sex and either AND/OR
```

hopefully that makes sense

Comment: You'd get better suggestions if you show your current implementation, y'know...

Comment: @Ekin ok i added it, not sure it makes sense though

Comment: You're asking about what is commonly called a query builder.  Are you looking for recommendations on query builders by 3rd parties or do you want/need to build your own?

Comment: @Khyron if you have some suggestions then please let me know! if you could tell me the name of some 3rd party builders then that would be great, or if making my own isn't too complicated then that's fine too.

Comment: Honestly it depends more on your requirements and how strong your Query foo is as to what anybody would recommend.  In your case I would suggest searching for "PDO query builder" and take a look at some libraries and the examples/documentation.  In terms of building your own, a simple way is an array of keyvaluepairs with keys being table columns and values being the search parameters, then write a function to convert that array to a string.